# How to SELECT COUNT(column_name) in laravel mongodb

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-mongodb

How can we retrieve the size of an array in the [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)'s `get()` function?

Update: Ultimately, I want to get the size of the array column for each qualified document

Example, for each document, I have an array of members data. Therefore, I would like to know for each document, how many members are there.

From Laravel's perspective, I could just load the entire member list for all qualified records and use `count()` to get the array size in blade template. But I wanna avoid that because it will cause loading issue if the member list for each record is huge.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `Model::where(column, condition)->count();` if Model extends `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model`

Or `DB::collection(collectionName)->where(column, condition)->count();`

You can find out more here: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#readme

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but I wasn't looking to get the count of qualified records. I am looking to get the size of the array column for each qualified records. Maybe my example MySQL query is inaccurate

Comment: Are they related records? Do you have a separate Member model class?